# How to avoid name conflict between global variable and a function in imported library?

Tags: c++

I am trying to import a Excel COM object so that I can read and write Excel cell data in my C++ program.

But when I import necessary for COM, it said
there is a name conflict between a global variable in my program and a function name in imported library.
I don't want to modify my global variable name to else because it has been used in many places.

Is there another way to avoid this conflict?
the following is my MWE.

```
//MicroSoft Office Objects
#import "C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\microsoft shared\OFFICE12\mso.dll"\
    rename("DocumentProperties","DocumentPropertiesXL")\
    rename("RGB","RBGXL")


int connect;

int main(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{


    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Option 1: Don't use global variables. This is the best option.

Option 2: Introduce a namespace:

```
namespace my_project {
    int connect;  
};
```

Then you can access this using `my_project::connect`, or putting `using namespace my_project;` or `using my_project::connect;` in files where you use it.

Comment: Thank you very much. I will use namespace .